# android widget, what to do after configure activity

Tags: android, android-widget

i have a pretty standard android widget, that starts it's configure activity, where you can set up several options.

now what should i do after the setup is finished. cause when i press the back or home button the widget is not there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on the configuration being finished or not, you should set the activity result.

```
setResult(RESULT_OK);
```

or

```
setResult(RESULT_CANCELLED);
```

And additionally, you might want to call the ACTION_WIDGET_UPDATE broadcast for your widget, like that for instance:

```
Intent updateWidget = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                 <YourWidgetClass>.class);
updateWidget.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
int[] ids = { widgetId };
updateWidget.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, ids);
sendBroadcast(updateWidget);
```